# How can I connect a USB DVD to VirtualBox 5.0?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, dvd

How can I connect a USB DVD to oracle VirtualBox 5.0 in Windows XP?  I tried using the settings and storage selections, but it was not listed there.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I connect a USB DVD to oracle VirtualBox 5.0 in Windows XP?

Easy. These screenshots are from VirtualBox in Mac OS X, but the general concept should work for any system running VirtualBox 5.0.

Basically since USB devices connected to a system running VirtualBox can be used by the system’s host OS as well as the guest OS on VirtualBox, VirtualBox has a “device filter” setup to allow you to select which USB devices should be used by the VirtualBox guest OS instead of the main system’s host OS.

First, shut down the virtual machine. Make sure the USB drive is plugged in an powered up so the host OS can recognize it. Now select the “Settings” for that virtual machine and choose the “Ports” option/tab which should look something like this:

[image]

In that area, select the USB part which should then look like this:

[image]

Make sure “Enable USB Controller” is checked and at least one of the USB controller types is selected. I would defer to “USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller” for now.

With that done you see that little icon that looks like a USB plug with a plus (`+`) over it? Click on that and select the USB DVD drive from that menu. Once selected, it should show up in your list of items under “USB Device Filters.”

Once that’s done, just click “OK” and start up your virtual machine.

Comment: OP asked specifically for Windows, but figured I'd note that if someone running Linux stumbles across this, you will need to follow these same steps and then add your user to the `vboxusers` group. Log out and back into your host system to apply changes and USB devices will show up when clicking the USB with the `+` in the final step. These instructions still work for me using Ubuntu 20.04 and VBox 6.32.

Comment: @ShaunReed This is good info! This comment is not really going to be seen by many. If you wish, you can do this: Ask a new question and reference the original question here. Say something like, “How can I connect a USB DVD to VirtualBox in Linux?” Basically re-ask the question in the context of this question and then post this comment as an answer; add screenshots if you wish! But this is good info and will benefit the community.