# How to connect USB DVD drive to VirtualBox on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox

Coming from this other Windows focused question, “[How can I connect a USB DVD to VirtualBox 5.0](https://superuser.com/q/984158/167207)” where I followed the instructions in [the answer by Giacomo1968](https://superuser.com/a/984164/167207).

Unfortunately, when doing that with Ubuntu 20.04 my guest VM still can not see my USB DVD drive. The guest doesn't detect any USB devices at all, I've also tried using USB storage drives.

Comment: Excellent self-solved post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [VirtualBox Extensions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and be sure the version matches with your VirtualBox version.

You can then install the VirtualBox Extensions with a command

```
sudo vboxmanage extpack install --replace ~/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.32.vbox-extpack
```

**Or** you can optionally do the same through the VirtualBox GUI if you navigate to `File->Preferences` in VirtualBox -

[image]

Use the GUI to select the extensions file you downloaded from Virtualbox, and input your `sudo` password, the installation should run after you accept the user agreement. For VirtualBox to detect USB devices, we also need to add our user to the `vboxusers` group. To do this, run the following commands. In the below command, my username is `kapper` and you should replace this with your username.

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxusers kapper
```

To verify your user has been added to the group, run the following command and check that the output produced shows you're in `vboxusers` group.

```
groups kapper

kapper : kapper adm cdrom sudo dip video plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare wireshark docker vboxusers
```

Then you will need to log out and back in to your system for the changes to be applied. I usually just run `reboot`.

Accessing the devices should be as simple as starting the VM and navigating to the toolbar and selecing `Devices->USB-><Your device>`

[image]

**Be careful**, if you attach a USB 3.0 device when USB 2.0 controller is activated, you will get `Failed to create a proxy device for the USB device. (Error: VERR_PDM_NO_USB_PORTS).` error when you try to attach the device. Make sure this setting reflects the devices you're using.

[image]